# Functions in javascript are not running, with no error

Tags: javascript, function

I am using Replit.
The functions are not running, only the "myfunction" in the function check runs. The rest don't run when I press the buttons. However, these functions work in the index, when I put them in a different script, it stops working.
Html script calling the functions

```
<button id = "check" onclick='check()'>Show answers</button>
 <button id = "color" onclick="color()">check</button>
```

The annoying function in js that has ben bothering me for weeks...

```
let pg=0;
    var answer;
    let ants;
    let qtitle;
        let question;
        let squestion;
    
    function check()
    { 
     switch(pg){ //different header number is fine but do '' BUT input box will still be there
    case 0:
    qtitle="What do you know?"
    ants = ['calculations'] 
         question=["Element Symbol that has the atomic number of... ","atomic mass of (round to nearest whole number)..."] 
             squestion=["1. 50","2. 2","3. 20","4. K"] 
      case 1:  
    ants = ["0","11","11","4","9","Be","8","8","8"] 
    question=["Sodium has 11 protons and an mass of 23. What is the...","An atom has an atomic# of 4 and 5 neutrons What is the...", "Oxygen has 8 electrons and a mass of 16"] 
    
    squestion=["charge","atomic#","#of electrons", "#of protons","Mass","element symbol", "#of protons", "atomic#", "#of neutrons"] 
    
        //  ants = ["Sn  ","He ","Ca ","39 ", "32  ","Sn ","He ","Ca",] 
        //  question=["Element Symbol that has the atomic number of... ","atomic mass of (round to nearest whole number)..."] 
        // squestion=["1. 50","2. 2","3. 20","4. K"] 
          break;
          case 2:
      ants = ["Carbon", "Chlorine", "Bromine",'Br',"Li","Sc","2","8","8" ] 
      question=["Carbon", "Chlorine", "Bromine", "Helium",'Br',"Li","Sc" ] 
      squestion=[] 
          }
        
     
    // var textBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=CO]');
    // var textToWrite;
    // for(var i in textBoxes){
    //    textToWrite = textBoxes[i].value;
    //   console.log(textToWrite)
    // }
    
    let lowAnts = [] //loop will place lower case values of ants in here
          // if(ants.toLowercase())
          for (let i= 0; i < ants.length; i++){
              lowAnts[i] = ants[i].toLowerCase() ;
          }
     
    console.log(ants)
    let text="";
      let loopNum = 0;
      myfunction();
    function myfunction() {
      console.log(ants.length);
      for(let i = 0; i < ants.length; i++){
      loopNum ++;        //increase number of array by 1 each time
     
      if(loopNum === 3){          //if it gets to 3, break and reset to 0, so it starts again
      text += (i + 1) + "." + ants[i] + "<br>"; 
      loopNum = 0;
      }else{ //if it is not 3,(cant go over since it restarts everytime), then it will just do this, without breaking
        text += (i + 1) + "." + ants[i] + "&nbsp;"+ "&nbsp;"+ "&nbsp;"+ "&nbsp;"
        // "⋅    " ;
      }
      if(i==9){
       loopnum=4
     }
      }
       
    
    }
    //  }
    //       let text="";
    
    //   ants.forEach(myfunction);
    // function myfunction(item, index) {
    //   text += (index + 1) + "." + item + "<br>"; 
    // }
    //can also be put at the bottom
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
        
       }
    
       function color()
      {
        console.log("color")
        input=document.querySelector(input[type=text])
    
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
     {console.log("works")
           }  
           }
```

Thanks, this problem has been driving me crazy over the past few weeks.

Comment: For one thing, `pg` is always 0 and thus would always trigger your first case statement. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: no error in the console and the switch statement, isn't the problem, I tried commenting it out, it's just that nothing in the function is working expet the "my function" in the function check. even the console.log isn't working